# How to correctly transform data for a stack chart chartJS (data transformation)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

**There is data that comes from the server**

```
  const groupedChartData = [
    {
      duration: '00:00:10',
      stats: [
        {color: 'red', reason: 'yes', value: 11},
        {color: 'green', reason: 'no', value: 33},
      ]
    },
    {
      duration: '00:01:00',
      stats: [
        {color: 'black', reason: 'call back', value: 32},
        {color: 'green', reason: 'no', value: 77},
      ]
    },
    {
      duration: '00:10:00',
      stats: [
        {color: 'red', reason: 'yes', value: 14},
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Based on the data from the server, you need to generate the following object for correct display
data on the chart, that is, each first value from the stats object in groupedChartData must correspond

to the first in the next object, the second to the second, and**

**exprected result**

```
let result = [
  {
    data: [11, 32, 14],
    backgroundColor: ['red', 'black', 'red']
  },
   {
    data: [33,77],
    backgroundColor: ['green', 'green']
  }
]
```

**[image: This transformation is necessary for me to form a chart of this kind in chartJS. Perhaps I am doing something wrong and such a complex transformation is not needed? In any case, the essence of the question is how to bring 1 structure that I receive from the server to the one that I described in the expected result]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the commented code below helps you:

```
const result = []

groupedChartData.forEach(el=>{
  el.stats.forEach((el, ind)=>{
    //checking if position is null
    if(result[ind] == null){
      result[ind] = {data:[], backgroundColor: []}
    }
    //pushing new values to the new array
    result[ind].data.push(el.value)
    result[ind].backgroundColor.push(el.color)
  })
})

console.log(result)
```